# How can I append an element after another in the document head?

Tags: javascript, html

I need to inject style elements into the head section of my html using JavaScript. For some context I am using webpack to inject styles. I have a function that is supposed to inject styles at an id inside of my head tags.

This is what my html looks like:

```js
function insertAtElement(element) {
  var target = document.getElementById(
    "inject-theme-styles-here"
  );
  target.appendChild(element);
}
```

```html
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <title>Webpack tutorial</title>
  <noscript id="inject-theme-styles-here"></noscript>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="root"></div>
</body>
```

I am not getting my desired output. In the element tab in chrome it adds it inside the  tag. But I need it to be added right below it not inside of it.

Comment: Why are you using a `noscript` tag? Because that's [not for what you seem to think](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/noscript).

Comment: Im not sure I didnt want to use a div in the head section what are the other options?

Comment: you insert `<link>` or `<script>`, or if you need verbatim styles, you use `<style>` (but inline style is typically dubious and you want to link to stylesheets/scripts if you can. You also don't preallocate them, you just build them when you need them, then add them to the `<head>` element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want your element to be added after `target`, instead of using `target.appendChild(element);` which appends a *child* element to target, use the following:

```js
target.parentNode.insertBefore(element, target.nextSibling);
```

Comment: This worked and is what I am looking for

Answer (score 0):

Create manually a script, set the src attribute and put it inside the head using tag name (or querySelector if you wish)

```js
// create a script element
let theScript = document.createElement("script");

// define it as javascript script
theScript.setAttribute("type","text/javascript");

// set the src
theScript.setAttribute("src","src/myscript.js");

// insert into the head
document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(theScript);
```